# Shortcut Key to copy full file path in JetBrains IDE (PhpStorm, PyCharm, WebStorm etc..)

Tags: phpstorm, pycharm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is there any **Shortcut Key** or **Option** to *Copy the full file path* on which you are working?

Like: /var/www/html/code/info.php or /code/info.php

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Right click on editor tab or on entry in Project View and choose "Copy path" action.

Alternatively: **Edit | Copy Path** (<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + C</kbd> here on Windows keymap). You can adjust the shortcuts in the `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` as needed.

If you need it to be relative to the project root -- use **Copy Relative Path** action instead.

**Please note** that this action is context dependant: when focus is on file (e.g. in Project View or some popup with files) it will be "Copy Relative Path" ... but when invoked inside the editor .. it will become "Copy Reference" (and will copy Class/Variable name etc).

**UPDATE 2022-08-19:**

Modern IDE versions have these commands under a single popup menu:

[image]

Invoked in the Project View context:

[image]

Invoked in the Editor context:

[image]

---

Another option is to use custom plugin that provides such actions. There are few that can do that and more (even if invoked right from the Editor).

Answer (score 3):

It is strange, but in the latest version, JetBrains removed this option from the context menu (right-click on the file name tab) + removed from the `Edit` top menu.

So the alternative is to use triple-click on the `shift` + type `copy path` there.

Comment: **Copy Reference** gives you more options, including **Absolute Path**

Comment: I ended up adjusting the context menu described here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/customize-actions-menus-and-toolbars.html so I only need 2 clicks to copy a relative path